# Want to programe my phone so that when i plug an aux cord the music app will automaticly start

Tags: music

I want to programe my phone so that as i plug in my headset(aux) a music app will start simultaneously.

Comment: Good idea. Just go ahead! Do you also have a question? This is a Q&A site, so the "question" part usually should contain a question. Making a guess: Have you searched the playstore for "headset control"? Some nice apps there doing exactly what you describe :)

Answer (score 0):

you can try [NRG Player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mrgreensoft.nrg.player&hl=en).It has all the functions you need with headset.